# How to get wcf response in parts

Tags: c#, wcf

I have to show multiple graph on WindowsApplication for that I select some parameter from UI. Copy those in request(Object) and send it to WCF service side. Based on request parameter we do some processing and create response in a list format and send it back to client. In complete process, server takes around 18 second performing business logic and after that client takes around 6 to 8 second to show graph on UI for all List(Graph generates for each Response object). Here client need to wait around 18 second as business is processing. Client graph generation time could be saved if we send the data in parts instead of complete List. So My concern is how to sends response data in parts(peaces).

Comment: It's best to use `async/await` for your purpose. Check out this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx

Comment: What wcf binding you use, what is the size of average single wcf message? Convertt it to byte[] and count. Maybe the problem is not your message size.

Answer (score 0):

IT's a matter of what the WCF service is doing. It spends some time executing the business logic (which probably includes time to connect to a DB and execute some SQL) and then sends out the data over the wire. How long will it take the data to land at the client is not something that a you can influence by programming.

However, if the business logic takes too long, this indicates that many operations are taking place on the service side in order to prepare the response. To optimize, you can divide those operations on smaller ones and expose endpoint methods for each one.  Then on the client side you call those methods subsequently and update your UI appropriately between the calls. This way you'll receive response from the service faster for SOME of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options that came to my mind:

1. Have a callback function that the server-side will call each time it has an update for that request. The client will request the processing from the WCF and will pass a function to be called by the server. The server will call that function for each piece of information.
2. The server will have two methods. The one will be a "begin processing" that will start for your processing request and will return a unique ID for that processing request. The second method will be for inquiring if there is any new piece of information.
   Something like this:

   `var requestId = serverProxy.BeginProcessing(inputData);
    var response = serverProxy.InquireProgress(requestId);
    while(!response.Completed) 
   {
   //Here you check if the response contains any new piece of information and then sleep for some time.
   }`

I would prefer the second option even though it involves more code, because in that way the server doesn't have to "know" his clients. It is on the client to check if their are any updates.
In addition, if you do choose the second option then I'd also write a small SDK wrapper that will just expose these two server methods + looping logic behind one Async method.

Hope this helps